# A formula to count the number of primes in an certain range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am a beginner in Google Sheets formulas, so I do not know anything in this area. I need to know a formula that returns the number of primes. I'm very sure primality testing algorithms are not very simple (I've never made one before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a scripted solution for:

- detecting primes: `=ISPRIME(A1)`
- counting primes in a range: `=COUNTPRIME()`
- counting composite numbers in a range: `=COUNTCOMPOSITE()`

credit to [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11214808/)

```
function ISPRIME(n) {
  if(typeof n !== "number") return false;
  if(Math.floor(n) !== n) return false;
  if(n <= 1) return false;
  if(n <= 3) return true;
  if(n % 2 === 0 || n % 3 === 0) return false;
  for(var i = 5; i*i <= n; i += 6) {
    if(n % i === 0  || n % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function COUNTPRIME() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:T25");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var count = 0
  values.forEach(function (array){
    array.forEach(function (value){
      if (ISPRIME(value)) count++;
    })
  })
  return count;
}
function COUNTCOMPOSITE() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:T25");
  var values = range.getValues();
  var count = 0
  values.forEach(function (array){
    array.forEach(function (value){
      if (!ISPRIME(value)) count++;
    })
  })
  return count;
}
```

**note:** change `A1:T25` in the script to reflect your range

Answer (score 1):

this formula will work up to ~11-digit prime (tested: 10000000019)

```
=IF(A1=2,TRUE,IF(AND(MOD(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("2:"&ROUNDUP(SQRT(A1),0))))<>0),TRUE,FALSE))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: So you're saying that this works up to a hundred billion? Because my numbers are from 1-200 :D

Comment: Well, looks like I asked the wrong question. I should have asked how to get the **number of primes** in a certain range (A1:T25).

Comment: Can you change your answer so that it can count the number of primes in an certain range?

Comment: @whoreallycares2 then you should ask new one instead of changing it after the correct answer was posted...

Comment: How exactly should I share my sheet? I do not want to give away my email address, since it is a school email that may reveal my location, etc. Maybe I could give you a .csv or .tsv

Answer (score 0):

add this script:

```
function ISPRIME(n) {
  if(typeof n !== "number") return false;
  if(Math.floor(n) !== n) return false;
  if(n <= 1) return false;
  if(n <= 3) return true;
  if(n % 2 === 0 || n % 3 === 0) return false;
  for(var i = 5; i*i <= n; i += 6) {
    if(n % i === 0  || n % (i + 2) === 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

create Sheet2 and populate it like this:

[image: 0]

with formula: **`=ISPRIME('SHEETNAMEHERE'!A1)`** and drag down and then to the right. when done hide whole sheet and use simple formula to count all primes:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A1:T25, TRUE)
```